# Importing a menu with dropdown on my html pages but z-index does not send the dropdown to the front

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried z-index but it seems to not do anything (-1 to the p tag, 1 and 2 to the dropdown) maybe it's an error in the way they are displayed ie. "grid"? Should I display them as block maybe that would do but it would be really awesome if I could send the elements on the page to the back while the menu is overlaying the page elements on the change function.

I'm stuck on this. Sorry for the much untidiness of the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="works.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.4.1/css/ionicons.min.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <script type="text/javascript" href="menu.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <header class="mainheader">
      <div class="containerr" onclick="myFunction(this)">
      <div class="bar1" ></div>
      <div class="bar2" ></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
      <div id="disp2">
      <div id="disp" class="meniutog">
      <div class="contulmeu">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" id="cnt">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="">Contul meu</a>
      </div>
      <div class="akscont">
      <span  class="fa fa-home" style="margin-right: 15px;">&nbsp;</span>
          <a href="works.html">Acasa</a>
      </div>

      <div class="produse">

        <span class="fa fa-map" style="text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;</span>
        <a href="toateprodusele.html"> Toate Produsele</a>
      </div>
       <div class="info2" href="">

        <span class="fa fa-info-circle fa-1x">&nbsp;</span>
       <label>Info</label>
      </div>
       <div class="localizare">

         <span class="fa fa-globe">&nbsp;</span>
        <a href="localizare.html">Localizare magazin</a>
        <label></label>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    function myFunction(x) {
        x.classList.toggle("change");

    }
        </script>
    </header>
    </body>
    </html>


    css


    body {
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif; margin:0
    }

    .meniutog{display:none; height:300px; width:240px; background-color:#f4f4f4; transition:1s;}



    .meniutog a:link{text-decoration:none; }
    .meniutog a{color:#333; border-bottom:1px solid #fafafa; width:auto;vertical-align: middle;}

    .containerr {display: inline-block;height:34px; width:34px;cursor: pointer;}
     #disp .aks{font-size:15px; margin-top:3px;}
    #disp a{height:auto; height:30px; vertical-align: middle; margin-left:-3px;}
    #esz{margin-right: 16px; font-size:31px;}


    .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
        width: 35px;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: #333;
        margin: 6px 0;
        transition: 0.7s;
    }
    .change #disp{display:none;}
    .change .bar1 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    }

    .change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}
    .change #disp{display:grid; transition-duration:1s;}



    .change .bar3 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    }

    a:link{text-decoration:none;}
    a:link{text-decoration-color: #f4f4f4;}





    .contulmeu, .akscont, .produse, .info2, .localizare{ font-size:15px; margin-top:15px; border-bottom-color: #fafafa; border-bottom:2px solid #fafafa; text-indent: 10px;}
    .localizare{text-indent:10px;display:inline-block; }
    i {display: inline-block;margin-right: 1em;}

    .c4 {text-indent: 10px;}
    #inf {display:block;}
    .c5 { padding-left: 15px;}
    .my-icon {vertical-align: middle;}
    .glyphicon-user:before:{}
     .fa-globe:before {margin-right:18px;}
    .fa-map:before { margin-right:14px;}
    .fa-info-circle:before {margin-right:18px;}









    @media screen and (max-width: 450px) {


    }

    #works {
    }

    .mainheader {
        width:100%;
    }

    .test {
        z-index: -1;
    }



    page example of import



    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="works.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.4.1/css/ionicons.min.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <script type="text/javascript" href="menu.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#works").load("works.html");
    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <nav>
    <div id="works"></div>
    </nav>
    <div class="test"><p>test</p></div>




    </body>
    </html>

[the paragraph tag is not pushed down or viewed in the back but I would prefer to have the elements not visible and active while the change function][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position : relative;`

```
.test {
    z-index: -1;
    position : relative;
}
```

I'm not good english, hope to help you